# Jade-cli - saving folder structure gives an error

Tags: node.js, npm, pug

I'm using jade-cli to compile my project from .jade files into .html.

Jade files have following hierarchy:

```
components
  views
  templates
  ...
```

I want rendered result to have same folder structure and trying to use `-H` attribute as it is said in documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade-cli

However when I'm using command `jade -P -H src -o dst` npm returns following error:

```
silly lifecycle @~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'jade -P -H src -o dst' ]
    12 silly lifecycle @~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
info lifecycle @~build: Failed to exec build script
verbose stack Error: @ build: `jade -P -H src -o dst`
verbose stack Exit status 1
verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:255:16)
verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program     Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:877:16)
verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit     (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program     Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
error node v6.9.1
error npm  v3.10.8
error code ELIFECYCLE
error @ build: `jade -P -H src -o dst`
error Exit status 1
error Failed at the @ build script 'jade -P -H src -o     dst'.
error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
error not with npm itself.
error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
error     jade -P -H src -o dst
error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project     with:
error     npm bugs
error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
error     npm owner ls
error There is likely additional logging output above.
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

If `-H` is excluded everything runs fine. What seems to be the problem?

npm version: 6.9.1
jade version: 1.11.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved. My mistake was that I thought **jade-cli** was part of common jade package. Appears that you have to install it separately using

```
npm i jade-cli -g
```

`-g` for installing it globally.

After this compilation goes successfully and creates all necessary folder architecture